# Not able to visible image using assetManager.registerLocator (Jmonkey)

Tags: android, jmonkeyengine

i am  trying to run examples from [this tutorial](http://jmonkeyengine.org/wiki/doku.php/jme3#tutorials_for_beginners).
 I downloaded town.zip and placed in my folder .. .. When try to run .. its showing blank screen. Then i added this following line

```
 DirectionalLight sun = new DirectionalLight();
  sun.setDirection(new Vector3f(-0.1f, -0.7f, -1.0f));
    rootNode.addLight(sun);
```

its working fine in simulator.. but still its showing blank in android devices..How to fix this issue

Comment: Got soloution..  Replaced with Spatial gameLevel = assetManager.loadModel("main.scene");
             Spatial gameLevel = assetManager.loadModel("Scenes/town/main.j3o"); //Repalced.

Comment: You should add an answer and accept it so others know you've solved your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replaced with Spatial gameLevel = assetManager.loadModel("main.scene"); Spatial gameLevel = assetManager.loadModel("Scenes/town/main.j3o"); //Repalced.